# .NET Regex for SQL Server string... but not Unicode string?

Tags: sql-server, regex, string

I'm trying to build a .NET regex to match SQL Server constant strings... but not Unicode strings.

Here's a bit of SQL:

```
select * from SomeTable where SomeKey = 'abc''def' and AnotherField = n'another''value'
```

Note that within a string two single quotes escapes a single quote.

The regex should match 'abc''def' but not n'another''value'.

I have a regex now that manages to locate a string, but it also matches the Unicode string (starting just after the N):

```
'('{2})*([^']*)('{2})*([^']*)('{2})*'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will do most of what you are looking to do:

```
(?<unicode>n)?'(?<value>(?:''|[^'])*)'
```

The upside is that it should accurately match any number of escaped quotes.  (`SomeKey = 'abc''''def'''` will match `abc''''def''`.)

The downside is it also matches Unicode strings, although it captures the leading `n` to identify it as a Unicode string.  When you process the regular expression, you can ignore matches where the match group "unicode" was successful.

The pattern creates the following groups for each match:

```
unicode: Success if the string is a Unicode string, fails to match if ASCII
value: the string value.  escaped single quotes remain escaped
```

If you are using .NET regular expressions, you could add `(?(unicode)(?<-value>))` to the end of the pattern to suppress matching the value, although the pattern as a whole would still match.

**Edit**

Having thought about it some more, the following pattern should do exactly what you wanted; it will not match Unicode strings at all.  The above approach might still be more readable, however.

```
(?:n'(?:''|[^'])*'[^']*)*(?<!n)'(?<value>(?:''|[^'])*)'
```

Comment: I decided to use your (?<unicode>n)?'(?<value>(?:''|[^'])*)' and a MatchEvaluator to handle the replace I was doing. Note that your second regex matches both ansi strings and unicode strings. Thanks!