# RegEx for SQL Server string to replace with unicode prefix

Tags: sql-server, regex, string

i have a similar problem like this:
[.NET Regex for SQL Server string... but not Unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099475/net-regex-for-sql-server-string-but-not-unicode-string)

The RegEx `(?:N'(?:''|[^'])*'[^']*)*(?<!N)'(?<value>(?:''|[^'])*)'` doesn't match this string correctly:

`Insert into SomeTable (someColumns) values ('someValue', N'someValue', 'someValue')`

it recognizes `"N'someValue', 'someValue'"` as a Match

I cant figure out to correct the RegEx to match all string literals but not the literals with the N-Prefix.

Like mentioned in the Link above the RegEx have to ignore escaped quotes in the space of the string like `'some '' escaped'`

Comment: Something tells me it's better to solve this without REGEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there is a better tool for your job - the [TSql100Parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql.tsql100parser(v=vs.100).aspx) class:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom;
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<ParseError> errors = new List<ParseError>();
        var tsql = @"
                Insert into SomeTable (someColumns) 
                values ('someValue1', 
                        N'someValue2', 
                        'someValue3',
                        'some '' escaped')";
        var result = GetLiterals(tsql);
    }

    private static List<string> 
        GetLiterals(string strQuery)
    {
        var parser = new TSql100Parser(false);
        IList<ParseError> errors = new List<ParseError>();
        var result = 
            parser.GetTokenStream(new StringReader(strQuery), errors);
        return result
            .Where(t =>
                t.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.AsciiStringLiteral ||
                t.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.UnicodeStringLiteral)
            .Select(t => t.Text)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

You can't use Type-3 grammars (regular expression) to parse Type-0 grammars (T-SQL). The same stands when you try to [parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/674700). It will not be 100% fail proof in real life.

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately i have to implement it in delphi :(

I managed to implement it with a less complex RegEx to find the String literals and some manual parsing

Comment: Maybe you've already read it, but if not, this question's answers could be helpful: [Need in SQL parser on Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615608/need-in-sql-parser-on-delphi).